# Is there a unique filter in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I have a json as follows:

```
[{
  "_id": "58a58ea23744cd46918914ef",
  "entityId": "ce7200c1-3430-47ce-ab81-7d0622cb8cae",
  "name": "Portugal",
  "description": "Portugal",
  "type": "country",
  "category": "common",
  "subcategory": "common",
  "parent": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8966"
  },
  "image": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8965"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "primary": "pt",
    "taxRate": 20,
    "exchangeRate": 0.7,
    "language": "PT",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8964"
  }
}, {
  "_id": "58a58ea23744cd46918914f1",
  "entityId": "815b9e90-e36f-4488-ad50-6a259b6d034d",
  "name": "Qatar",
  "description": "Qatar",
  "type": "country",
  "category": "common",
  "subcategory": "common",
  "parent": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8969"
  },
  "image": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8968"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "primary": "qa",
    "taxRate": 20,
    "exchangeRate": 0.7,
    "language": "RO",
    "currency": "RO",
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8967"
  }
}, {
  "_id": "58a58ea23744cd46918914f2",
  "entityId": "e12ea227-c05c-42cf-b746-6bc537812a02",
  "name": "Romania",
  "description": "Romania",
  "type": "country",
  "category": "common",
  "subcategory": "common",
  "parent": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a896c"
  },
  "image": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a896b"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "primary": "ro",
    "taxRate": 20,
    "exchangeRate": 0.7,
    "language": "RO",
    "currency": "RON",
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a896a"
  }
}, {
  "_id": "58a58ea23744cd46918914f4",
  "entityId": "8c22ccaf-f7b7-4009-9642-54580ad5ad4e",
  "name": "Russia",
  "description": "Russia",
  "type": "country",
  "category": "common",
  "subcategory": "common",
  "parent": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8972"
  },
  "image": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8971"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "primary": "ru",
    "taxRate": 20,
    "exchangeRate": 0.7,
    "language": "RU",
    "currency": "RUB",
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8970"
  }
}, {
  "_id": "58a58ea23744cd46918914fa",
  "entityId": "725b2011-177b-4fc5-8e1f-559b3e4e8958",
  "name": "United States",
  "description": "United States",
  "type": "country",
  "category": "common",
  "subcategory": "common",
  "parent": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8984"
  },
  "image": {
    "_id": "58a8486ca4890027348a8983"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "primary": "us",
    "taxRate": 20,
    "exchangeRate": 0.7,
    "language": "EN",
    "currency": "USD",
    "_id": "58 a8486ca4890027348a8982"
  }
}, {
  "_id": " 58 a58ea23744cd46918914d8",
  "entityId": "af884be9 - 067 d - 4 dd2 - 8646 - 5738 f5bb0efb",
  "name": "Germany",
  "description": "Germany",
  "type": "country",
  "category": "common",
  "subcategory": "common",
  "parent": {
    "_id": "58 a8486ca4890027348a89b7 "
  },
  "image": {
    "_id": "58 a8486ca4890027348a89b6 "
  },
  "metadata": {
    "primary": "de",
    "taxRate": 20,
    "exchangeRate": 0.7,
    "language": "DE",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "_id": "58 a8486ca4890027348a89b5 "
  }
}]
```

And I'm displaying these values in dropdown with the following code:

**Template:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
    {{selectedCurrency}}
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li *ngFor="let currency of currencies">
      <a>{{currency.metadata.currency }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Right now if you see, metadata has duplicate currency **`"EUR"`** . Is there a pipe with angular2 so that I can display only the unique values of `metadata.currency`

Comment: No, you have to create your *custom* `pipe`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there a unique filter in angular 2?

No, you would have to create your custom pipe to do this.

However, I don't think create a `pipe` is really necessary, you can do it in your component.

You can get all the *unique* `currencies` of those items doing the following:

```
export class AnyComponent {

  items: any[];
  currencies: string[];

  constructor() {
    // Populate your items... "items = blabla"

    // Get all currencies
    const curr = items.map(data => data.metadata.currency);

    // Unique currencies
    this.currencies = curr.filter((x, i, a) => x && a.indexOf(x) === i);
  }
}
```

Then, in your **template**:

```
...
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  <li *ngFor="let currency of currencies">
    <a>{{currency}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be done in `ngOnInit`, not the constructor?

Comment: Well, it can be in both spots.

Comment: If `items` is an `@Input()`, will it be guaranteed to be available at the time the constructor runs?

Comment: No, it won't. It will be only available in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: this.curr = countries.map(function(lang){return lang.metadata.currency;});;
 this.currencies = [...new Set(this.curr)]; i am getting an error Type 'Set<string>' is not an array type.

Comment: @user2280016. Ok, check the edit and use the 2nd. version then.

Comment: Type 'Set<string>' is not an array type

Comment: now am getting unique ones but there is undefined as well. how to remove that?

Comment: Undefined? Is there any item that doesn't have the `currency` *property*?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a unique filter in angular 2?

No, there is not.

You should create the unique list in your component JS logic, for the same reason that it is recommended **not** to use pipes for filtering and sorting.

From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-:

> Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations. The user experience can degrade severely for even moderate sized lists when Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second.

You can create the unique list of currencies, omitting missing ones, with something like:

```
this.uniqueCurrencies = uniq(data.map(elt => elt.metadata.currency).filter(Boolean));
```

where `uniq` is any one of many versions available from libraries, or roll your own, or use `Set` as proposed in another answer.

Comment: do you have a sample in this case?